# Connecting to azure service fabric fails with 0x800b0109

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have set up a new Service Fabric instance and I can successfully connect to the Service Fabric Explorer to view the current state of the service. I would now like to connect to the Service Fabric instance using powershell:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint <path>:19000 -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint <PrimaryCertificateThumbprint> -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue <Admin Client certificate thumbprint installed locally> -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

Whenever I run this command I get the error:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : FABRIC_E_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: 0x800b0109
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this error and how I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is somewhat different from your command:

```
PS C:\> $ConnectArgs = @{  ConnectionEndpoint = 'mycluster.cloudapp.net:19000';  X509Credential = $True;  StoreLocation = 'CurrentUser';  StoreName = "MY";  ServerCommonName = "mycluster.cloudapp.net";  FindType = 'FindByThumbprint';  FindValue = "AA11BB22CC33DD44EE55FF66AA77BB88CC99DD00"   }
PS C:\> Connect-ServiceFabricCluster $ConnectArgs
```

Comment: I tried the ActiveDirectory login approach detailed in the docs: $ConnectArgs = @{  ConnectionEndpoint = '<path>:19000';  AzureActiveDirectory = $True; ServerCertThumbprint = "<thumprint>"   }. But now get "Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS issue."

Comment: How did you configure security in your cluster?

Comment: I added a primary certificate with the thumbprint <thumbprint> and also a secondary certificate. I also added a separate admin client thumbprint, but I'm only using that in the original post.

Comment: what happens if you omit '-ServerCertThumbprint <PrimaryCertificateThumbprint>' from the first command?

Comment: So, using the certificate sign in method, the error goes back to being Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : FABRIC_E_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: 0x800b0109 when I omit the -ServerCertThumbprint

Comment: I've RDP'd onto the cluster (this is a single node cluster for test purposes) and if I do  Connect-ServiceFabricCluster, it connects successfully. If I do Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint '...:19000' where ... is the the FQDN or localhost or 127.0.0.1 I get the error: "No cluster endpoint is reachable, please check if there is connectivity/firewall/DNS". I've tried turning off firewalls and nslookup for the FQDN seems to work.

Comment: Well I guess this is certificate related. I've deleted the service fabric instance completely and rebuilt it without any security and everything now works. I guess there must be something faulty with my user defined certificates.